# RecyclerView slide-in animation without clipping last item

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a RecyclerView where each item is a thumbnail implemented as fresco DraweeView. Depending on the size of the screen the last thumbnail is sometimes "clipped" when the RecyclerView is first loaded (which is ok).

I implemented animation to slide in the RecyclerView right to left on initial load. My animation uses OvershootInterpolator and this is where the issue is: while the overshoot is happening the last "clipped" item leaves the edge of the screen exposing that thumbnail is narrower than the one before it (note, normal scrolling of the RecyclerView does not have this issue).

Here is my slide_in_animation.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Here is a portion of the code loading the animation:

```
final Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
    R.anim.slide_in_animation);
// overshoot slightly further than the default tension of 2.0f
slideIn.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(2.5f));
myRecyclerView.startAnimation(slideIn);
```

Is there any way to have the last item that is only partially visible on the screen on initial load be fully visible when animated with OvershootInterpolator?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. Hope others can benefit from it:

1) use the LayoutParams of the container that has the RecyclerView to set the container width 1.5 times the current width.
2) do the slide-in animation
3) animate making the container width what it was prior to step 1 (decrease current width 1.5 times).